# Conditional JOINs in Class Table Inheritance in mySQL

Tags: mysql

> Is there a way to do a *conditional* JOIN so that it returns columns of either of one of the child tables based on a parent table field?

---

#### tl;dr:

I am trying to implement [Class Table Inheritance (aka Table Per Type Inheritance)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) in mySQL. AFAIK it's not offered out of the box so some hacking around is needed to make it tick.

Considering the following SQL schema.

[image: Customer]

#### What I'd like to do:

- Get records of `CustomerIndividual` *IF* they exist **OR** `CustomerOrganization` *IF* they exist.
- I'm passing around `idCustomer` for my `WHERE` clauses.

---

### An Ideal Result Set:

- **If `Customer.typeIndividual = TRUE`:**

[image: Result with <code>Customer</code> & <code>CustomerIndividual</code> columns combined]

- **If `Customer.typeOrganization = TRUE`:**

[image: Result with <code>Customer</code> & <code>CustomerOrganization</code> columns combined]

It's *important* to note that this query will always return **1 record only**, so yes the column number would be variable.

---

### What I'm currently doing:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Customer
  LEFT JOIN CustomerIndividual
  ON Customer.idCustomer = CustomerIndividual.idCustomer
  LEFT JOIN CustomerOrganization
  ON Customer.idCustomer = CustomerOrganization.idCustomer
  WHERE Customer.idCustomer = ?
```

but this of course:

- returns *ALL* columns for `Customer`, `CustomerIndividual` & `CustomerOrganization`
- returns even *duplicate* columns, e.g `idCustomer` which appears on all 3 tables.
- produces columns of `CustomerOrganization` even if the *Customer* is an *Individual* and vice-versa.

### My question:

Is there a way to do a *conditional* JOIN so that it returns columns of *either* of one of the child tables based on the `Customer.typeIndividual/Customer.typeOrganization` fields?

#### Notes:

- Either `Customer.typeIndividual` OR `Customer.typeOrganization` can be `TRUE` at any given time. Not both at the same time. The `Customer` can be either an `Individual` OR an `Organization`.
- I'm open to restructuring if it makes things more simple. I'm having the feeling that the `Customer.typeIndividual` OR `Customer.typeOrganization` differentiation flag I use is somehow redundant, i.e perhaps I could infer whether a `Customer` is an Individual/Organization by looking which of the child-tables is full.
- I'm aware I could make completely different queries on the application-level but yes, I'm looking for a silver-bullet.

Comment: Since Individual and Organization, encapsulate different columns, how do you imagine the unified table result to be? I don't think what you're trying to acomplish makes sense in relational databases, but i'd like to see an expert's opinion on that.

Comment: What is your desire output? Because you can have `Table1.<fields> + Table2.<fields>` but depending on Customer Type some of the fields will be null. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Sevle While they do encapsulate *some* different columns, they *share* all the columns of `Customer`. This is a well-known pattern as I describe in the question to achieve some type of inheritance.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The ideal output is described in the **An Ideal Result Set:** section of my question.

Comment: That is ideal result set isnt possible because you cant have a same column named two different ways. By your example result will give you Midden Name or RegistrationName

Comment: @Nicholas My dispute was not about having one instance of Customer's columns. I was referring to the Individual and Organization columns.

Comment: @Sevle Well, the ideal result would contain columns of `CustomerIndividual` OR `CustomerOrganization` based on the flags `Customer.typeIndividual/Customer.typeOrganization`. Plus it should *always* contain the columns of `Customer`.

Comment: Again Nicholas you **CANT** have  rows with 5 field and rows with 6 fields.. You could have rows with 9 field where some has 3 field NULLs (individual) or the other 2 fields NULLs (Organization).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ah now I understand what you are saying. Consider that this query should always return **1** record only.

Comment: Show us a sample of a table with your desire output and maybe we can understand it better. But right now I dont think is possible.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Again, the desired output is in the section above. The misunderstanding comes from the fact that I didn't specify that this query would always return *1* record ONLY. So yes the column number of the result should be variable.

Comment: When I say you show us a table I mean a real sample data. Words can be interpreted on different ways. And you save us from wasting our time trying to understand what you want.. What you describe now is a function. Send `customer_id` get his type and use `IF` to decide which query return.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do this, but I dont recommend it.

```
SELECT
  Customer.*,
  COALESCE(CI.firstName, CO.organizationName) AS firstName_or_organizationName,
  COALESCE(CI.maidenName, CO.registrationNo) AS maidenNamee_or_registrationNo,
  lastName --  here you get last_name or NULL if is an organization
  FROM Customer C
  LEFT JOIN CustomerIndividual  CI
         ON Customer.idCustomer = CustomerIndividual.idCustomer
  LEFT JOIN CustomerOrganization CO
         ON Customer.idCustomer = CustomerOrganization.idCustomer
  WHERE Customer.idCustomer = ?
```

Or use a store procedure

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE stored_procedure_name(IN CustomerID INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE boolTypeIndividual INT;

    SELECT Customer.typeIndividual into boolTypeIndividual
    FROM Customer
    WHERE Customer.idCustomer = CustomerID 

    IF (boolTypeIndividual) THEN
            SELECT C.*,   CI.*
            FROM Customer C
            LEFT JOIN CustomerIndividual  CI
                   ON Customer.idCustomer = CustomerIndividual.idCustomer
            WHERE Customer.idCustomer = CustomerID 
    ELSE
            SELECT C.*,   CO.*
            FROM Customer C
            LEFT JOIN CustomerOrganization CO
                   ON Customer.idCustomer = CustomerOrganization.idCustomer
            WHERE Customer.idCustomer = CustomerID 
    END IF
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Any comment on this solutiion?. Because you cant have a condition to return diinamic number number of columns, unless you create a dinamic query.

Comment: Was trying to create the result set examples you asked for. Well, yeah it seems like the number of columns would be dynamic. I should probably handle this at the application-level by getting the `type` first and then executing the appropriate query.

Comment: You can try with a store procedure.

Comment: Like a charm - thanks. I think you mean `Stored Procedure` instead